# Which Ant property contains the CWD when the ant script is run?

Tags: ant

I don't want to get the basedir -- that appears to contain the build.xml script -- I want the CWD of the call to ant itself.

Basically, I want to do this:

```
$ cd /home/chrisr/projects/some_project
$ ant -f ../../tools/ant-build-rules/library.xml build-library
```

At this point, I need two things:

1. The path to ant-build-rules in absolute form; this is currently found in the `basedir` property, so I'm set there.
2. The path of some_project, in absolute form. This is what I don't know how to get.

Which property contains this information?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The java property **user.dir** contains the current directory

```
<project name="demo" default="printCWD">
    <target name="printCWD">
        <echo message="${user.dir}"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such property, but you can run a script to get it.

```
${bsh:WorkDirPath.getPath()}
```

See [urbancode.com](http://lists.urbancode.com/pipermail/anthill-pro/2007-April/005702.html).